# Test classes doesn't work correctly on android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, kotlin-coroutines

I'm a newbie in unit testing in android and I follow [this repository](https://github.com/fevziomurtekin/DeezerClone) on implementing it  but when I done it and run it my test it passes always even if I make a different clear assertion
like that

```
MatcherAssert.assertThat(25, CoreMatchers.`is`(20))
```

so I thought I made something wrong and I tried to clone the repository and try it and found the repository also passed in all cases , I tried to change the MainCoroutineRule from [this](https://github.com/fevziomurtekin/DeezerClone/blob/master/app/src/sharedTest/MainCoroutineRule.kt) to [this](https://github.com/Pavneet-Sing/mvvm-flow-coroutine-testing/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com/pavneet_singh/mvvm_flow_coroutine_testing/MainCoroutineScopeRule.kt) and now the tests work but not passed

for example in Repository test it gives me this error

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :com.fevziomurtekin.deezer.core.data.ApiResult$Loading@5c7933ad
Actual   :Success(data=[AlbumData(diskNumber=1, duration=320, explicitContentCover=0, explicitContentLyrics=0,.......
```

and the method for that test case

```
  @ExperimentalTime
  @Test
  fun fetchAlbumTracksFromNetworkTest() = runBlocking {
    val mockData = AlbumDetailsResponse(data = listOf(MockUtil.album), total = 12)
    val returnData = Response.success(mockData)
    whenever(service.fetchAlbumDetails(MockUtil.albumID)).thenReturn(returnData)

    repository.fetchAlbumTracks(MockUtil.albumID).test {
      val result = expectItem()
      assertEquals(result, ApiResult.Success(listOf(MockUtil.album)))
      Assert.assertEquals((result as ApiResult.Success<List<AlbumData>>).data[0].title, "Alo")
      Assert.assertEquals(result.data[0].id, "425605922")
      Assert.assertEquals(result.data[1].title, "Geceler")
      Assert.assertEquals(result.data[1].id, "425605932")
      expectComplete()
    }

    verify(service, atLeastOnce()).fetchAlbumDetails(MockUtil.albumID)
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(service)
  }
```

and for Viewmodel it gives me this error

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
observer.onChanged(
    Success(data=[ArtistAlbumData(cover=https://api.deezer.com/album/51174732/image, cov
```

for this test case

```
 @Test
    fun fetchAlbumListTest() = runBlocking {
        val mockList = listOf(MockUtil.album)

        val observer : Observer<ApiResult<List<AlbumData>>> = mock()
        val fetchedData : LiveData<ApiResult<List<AlbumData>>> = repository.fetchAlbumTracks("302127").asLiveData()
        fetchedData.observeForever(observer)

        viewModel.fetchingAlbumDatas(MockUtil.albumID)
        delay(500L)

        verify(observer).onChanged(ApiResult.Success(mockList))
        fetchedData.removeObserver(observer)


    }
```

and for Api test [here](https://github.com/fevziomurtekin/DeezerClone/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com/fevziomurtekin/deezer/domain/network/DeezerServiceTest.kt) it also fails to read input stream from input json files

Did I setup anything wrong on test configuration which makes the tests fails or the tests itself is wrong,the weird is the repository which I used there are many test classes for the whole project and I wonder if it didn't work it won't be pushed!

update: I open an issue on the repository and it has more details of what happens [here](https://github.com/fevziomurtekin/DeezerClone/issues/30)

hope anyone can help with that?

Comment: What exactly want as a solution here? to fix the issue in the repo test case  or the reason that you are seeing the test as passed despite it should failed.

Comment: @DinkarKumar I want a solution for the reason that I'm seeing the test as passed despite it should failed .. maybe the tests in the repo has some problems but I can't even figure it out because of that reason which makes my tests always passed